# C# Loop through an index from a list which holds an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops

I created a list of arrays. But i am trying to access a specific index to pull the specific array so i can loop through. and get values from it. I am not even sure how to start the code.my list of arrays has items each with 1 aray with 5 valuse. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to know what language you're using!

Comment: You should post a snippet of your existing code.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this

```
List<int[]> l = new List<int[]>();
l.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
l.Add(new int[] { 2, 3, 4 });
l.Add(new int[] { 3, 4, 5 });
int a = l[2][2]; // a = 5
```

Comment: This shows the OP how to access a given element of a given array in the list, but not how to loop through a given array in the list, which is what they seem to be asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index in the List to loop through a specific array, if you know it's index.

For example, say you have a List named `listOfArrays`, and you want to loop through the second array:

```
foreach (int element in listOfArrays[1])
{
    // do something with the array
}
```

`listOfArrays[1]` will return the int[] in the second position in the List.

Alternatively, you could loop through the entire list and process each array like this:

```
foreach (int[] arr in listOfArrays)
{

    foreach (int element in arr)
    {

        // do something with the array
    }
}
```

But it sounds like you're looking to simply access a specified array in the list, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, some examples help you

```
List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>(); // <- MyList is list of arrays of int

// Let's add some values into MyList; pay attention, that arrays are not necessaily same sized arrays:

myList.Add(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
myList.Add(new int[] {4, 5, 6, 7, 8});
myList.Add(new int[] {}); // <- We can add an empty array if we want
myList.Add(new int[] {100, 200, 300, 400});

// looping through MyList and arrays 

int[] line = myList[1]; // <- {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
int result = line[2]; // <- 6

// let's sum the line array's items: 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; ++i)
  sum += line[i];

// another possibility is foreach loop:
sum = 0;

foreach(int value in line) 
  sum += value;   

// let's sum up all the arrays within MyList
totalSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; ++i) {
  int[] myArray = myList[i];

  for (int j = 0; j < myArray.Length; ++j)
    totalSum += myArray[j];  
}

// the same with foreach loop
totalSum = 0;

foreach(int[] arr in myList)
  foreach(int value in arr) 
    totalSum += value;
```